# Configure OutputCache with remote Redis in ASP.NET MVC 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, caching, redis, outputcache

I'm trying to connect to Redis for my OutputCache, I have configured this in the web.config (for localhost, all is working fine)

```
<system.web>
    <caching>
      <outputCache defaultProvider="localRedisOutputCache">
        <providers>
          <add name="localRedisOutputCache" type="Microsoft.Web.Redis.RedisOutputCacheProvider" host="127.0.0.1" accessKey="" ssl="false" />          
        </providers>

      </outputCache>
    </caching>
</system.web>
```

But when I change to my Azure Redis, it's not working...

```
<system.web>
    <caching>
      <outputCache defaultProvider="remoteRedisOutputCache">
        <providers>
          <add name="remoteRedisOutputCache" type="Microsoft.Web.Redis.RedisOutputCacheProvider" host="{{myName}}.redis.cache.windows.net" accessKey="{{MyAccessKey}}" ssl="true" />

      </outputCache>
    </caching>
</system.web>
```

I have read [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/redis-cache/cache-aspnet-output-cache-provider) and tested with all possibilities, but no results. I don't have an exception and the solution compile correctly.

What I'm missing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Try to specify the databaseId field in your web.config , check the following link and let me know https://www.captechconsulting.com/blogs/azure-redis-cache